# mock Observable concatMap function inside Unit test (Angular 5)

Tags: unit-testing, angular5, ngrx-store, angular-unit-test, concatmap

**Edit: I figured it out, the problem is `spyOn` will make the function it spy on to return `undefined`, need to call `and.callThough` explicitly.**

I'm trying to test my component, which uses ngrx store. I'm stubbing my store in that unit test like this:

`meetup-view.component.spec.ts`

```
class ActivatedRouteStub {
  private subject = new Subject();

  push(value) {
    this.subject.next(value);
  }

  get params() {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
}

class StoreStub {
  storeState = {
    auth: Observable.of({}),
    meetups: Observable.of([{key: '1'}])
  };

  select(value) {
    return this.storeState[value];
  }

  dispatch() {

  }
}

describe('MeetupCreateComponent', () => {
  let component: MeetupCreateComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MeetupCreateComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [FormsModule],
      declarations: [ MeetupCreateComponent ],
      providers: [
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useClass: ActivatedRouteStub },
        { provide: Store, useClass: StoreStub }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MeetupCreateComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should init edit/view mode correctly', () => {
    const route: ActivatedRouteStub = TestBed.get(ActivatedRoute);
    const store: StoreStub = TestBed.get(Store);
    const spy = spyOn(store, 'select').and.callThrough();
    route.push({id: 1});
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.editMode).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

the problem is, in my component, I use concatMap (and import it using `import 'rxjs/add/operator/concatMap';`)

`meetup-view.component.ts`

```
this.meetup$ = this.store.select('meetups')
        .concatMap(meetups => {
          return meetups.filter(m => m.key === key);
        });
```

and when I run my unit test, I always get this error: `Cannot read property 'concatMap' of undefined`.
I already tried to import `concatMap` to my unit tests but no luck. Been searching for hours now :(.

Comment: Could you please show more of the unit test, including construction of mock and TestBed where you tell it to provide the mock instead of the real store.

Comment: what is the output of `this.store.select('meetups')`? Did you mock the `this.store`?